# How to open running juptyer using VScode?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vscode-remote

I am trying to do it since a couple of days without success despite reading tons of last year info on the internet. I have a jupyter notbook server running either on a local or on a remote machine (with ports forwarded to the local machine). I want to open a jupyter notebook for edit in VScode (note, I do not want to start it from within VSCode, I really want to open the one from the running server).

Internet says that I have to type "Jupyter: Specify Jupyter server for connections" in the command pallette. The problem is that when I am trying to type it, there is simply no such option shown to me.

E.g. here [https://docs.cse.lehigh.edu/vscode/vscode-remote-jupyterhub/\](https://docs.cse.lehigh.edu/vscode/vscode-remote-jupyterhub/%5C)
or here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks

P.S. I do have python, jupyter and remote-ssh plugins installed.

Running VSCode 1.76.2, on Ubuntu 20.04

I tried to find anything related accessing a running jupyter server from VScode. The best I could find was getting a kernel from the running jupyter server.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server

But there is nowhere a way to open a **running notebook** or opening an existing .ipynb file using this kernel. Maybe there is some butting of checkbox I need to check in order for the " Jupyter: Specify Jupyter server for connections" to appear in the command palette. But I don't know where to look for it

What I need is to edit a jupyter notebook (that is run on a jupyter server on a local or a remote machine) in VScode.